# Is it possible, if we get a value from an input field on a method call to use this value later on a different method that is called in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a modal to get a title from the user. Save button is used to trigger Save() method which get the users title and closes modal. I want to use this title later on another method called for a different event. Is any possible way to keep this value and use it later, because since this value is saved to Save() method is a local variable. I am using Angular

```
<ng-template #template>
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title  col-md-10">Add topics</h4>
        <button type="button col-md-2" class="close pull-right" aria-label="close" (click)="closeModal()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-8  offset-2">
            <h5 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 2rem;">Enter Title</h5>
            <input [(ngModel)]="topicTitle" type="text" class="form-control" id="ChatTitle" placeholder="Enter Title">
          </div> 
    <div class="modal-body"><hr />
        <h5 class="text-center">Select tags that match you theme</h5>

        <ng-select [items]="tags"
               bindLabel="name"
               [multiple]="true"
               placeholder="Choose tags"
               [(ngModel)]="myTags"
               (change)="selectedTags($event)"
               >
    </ng-select>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Also onSaved() method which belongs to this component

```
topictitle = '';

onSave() {

console.log(this.topicTitle);
const btn = document.getElementById("addtopic");
this.modalService.hide(1);



  btn.innerHTML = "End topic";
  btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger');


  console.log(title);
  // New document creation
  this.savedService.createSavedDoc(this.topicTitle, this.myTags);
}
```

An example someExample() method will be called many times but i want to have the title value we got from onSave().

Comment: Which library are you using for the modal? Please add some code

Comment: Show some code, please add code snippets

Comment: I use BsModalService also i pasted code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had a typo or something in `topicTitle` in your html and typescript.
Here is a small working example.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularinput-avb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

When you need the title in the same component:

```
public title = '';

// please pass the title on method call from the template
public save(newTitle) {
    this.title = newTitle;
}
```

Or you need it in another component, just create a service to handle the title.

Comment: Both methods will be in the same component so i don't need a service to handle that. onSave() function is called first to get that value and the someExample() method will be called later many times but i need to have access to the title value that user set before.  If i use a global variable for title which will be a parameter to onSaved method and then set title = this.topicTitle, will that allow me to have this value on someExample() method?

Comment: Yes, in the `someExample()` method (in the same component) you can access the `title` value with `this.title`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, new time i will use how to ask reference before i write any question.